# Logitech Quickcam cannot be configured

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, logitech-webcam

I own a Logitech Quickcam and was able to set it up under Windows Vista with original drivers from the manufacturers website. It does run, send video and pictures all fine. Using its software I can even move the camera in all 4 directions, but cannot configure brightness, contrast and such. All controls to do that are disabled.

There is no other video or video enabled software running. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 3):

Although it may not be ideal, could you possibly adjust the brightness/contrast through the application your using the webcam with? I.E., your chat program

Answer (score 0):

Is Rightlight enabled?  It might automatically take over stuff like brightness, contrast, white balance, etc.